# Visual studio code can't run

Tags: software-installation, snap, visual-studio-code, runit

I have problem with running a Visual studio code on my Ubuntu 18.04, xps, dell 15" 9560.

I managed to install it from snap store and I remember it worked well until  installed few plugins like lint,syntax highlighting,  VSC its like start running in background I see on left top menu loading icon but then stops. Windows never shows.

What could be a problem? Or how to found VSC stat up logs?

Comment: Try re-installing after doing a system upgrade!

Comment: I installed it on clean ubuntu installation and tried few types of install of VSC and still nothing works. I was wondering how to investigate it app startup logs  on ubuntu.

Comment: Use this `code --verbose` to start it so you will see any errors!